# Use two Auth-Type PAP and EAP with FreeRadius

Tags: mysql, authentication, radius, freeradius, radius-protocol

I've freeradius server which uses MySQL to store the data.

following is my database

```
radcheck table
+-----+----------+--------------------+----+--------------+
| id  | username | attribute          | op | value        |
+-----+----------+--------------------+----+--------------+
| 474 | varun    | Cleartext-Password | := | sunshine3003 |
+-----+----------+--------------------+----+--------------+


radreply table
+----+----------+--------------+----+-------+
| id | username | attribute    | op | value |
+----+----------+--------------+----+-------+
|  1 | varun    | Fall-Through | =  | Yes   |
+----+----------+--------------+----+-------+


radgroupcheck table
+----+-----------+-----------+----+-------+
| id | groupname | attribute | op | value |
+----+-----------+-----------+----+-------+
|  1 | group1    | Auth-Type | := | PAP |
|  2 | eapgroup  | Auth-Type | := | EAP   |
+----+-----------+-----------+----+-------+


radusergroup table
+----------+-----------+----------+
| username | groupname | priority |
+----------+-----------+----------+
| varun    | eapgroup  |        1 |
| varun    | group1    |        2 |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

We have two different clients which uses two different Authentication types with free radius , One uses `PAP` and sends the Password in `User-Password` attribute.

and another client user `EAP` and sends the password in `EAP-Message` and `Message-Authenticator`

What i want is, when PAP fails to authenticate or when `User-Password` attribute is not present it should use `EAP` as `Auth-Type` and if `EAP` and `Message-Authenticator` are not present in radius attribute it should reply with Access-reject or Authentication failure message.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set `control:Auth-Type` manually.  This attribute is there so that modules in the `authorize` section can communicate with the rest of the server the type of authentication that should be run in the `authenticate` section.

In order to set `Auth-Type` based on attributes you should list the pap, eap etc... modules in turn in the authorize section, they'll check if the requisite attributes were in the request and determine the correct Auth-Type value.

If you want to make a policy to restrict certain users to certain types of authentication then set Auth-Type in the reply list (radgroupreply table), and check which Auth-Type has been set at the end of the authorize section.

```
authorize {
    eap
    pap
    sql

    if (control:Auth-Type != reply:Auth-Type) {
        reject
    }
}
```